# Div background goes behind another background in IE

Tags: css, overlap

If you look at my website in IE the NAV UL-LI it goes behind the NAV background but the content in UL-LI is above the NAV background.

SITE: [cyberbat.co.uk/test](http://www.cyberbat.co.uk/test)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks the same in IE9+FF+Chrome.

Comment: Only everything except PHP, that has a special class not to view the background but the others are normal li.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just downloaded it and strangely enough added ' ' in the background-image: url(' ') and it works now?
strange but true.

Here, I updated it in JSFiddle and it works(IE 8)
http://jsfiddle.net/xWRYt/

What I changed is simply

```
background-image:url(../images/nav_bg.png);
```

=>

```
background-image:url('../images/nav_bg.png');
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Delete it now, and if you don't I might take some action. Let me try ''.

Comment: Did I do something wrong? If so I apologize but please explain

Comment: I only wanted you too look at the source not to download it.

Comment: ok.. I'll delete it right away.. technically when you see something on the web the content is already downloaded onto your computer. I will hoever erase every copy.

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem.. Does it work for you in the JSFiddle link I put in the answer? http://jsfiddle.net/xWRYt/

Comment: I suggest trying this:
in .header .nav ul li {
display: inline-block;}
just cause I have no idea why it behaves differently in two places.
Let me know if it makes a difference?

Comment: It just pushed it down a little.

Comment: Does it work okay offline? If you just copy the html file to your pc?

Comment: It works perfectly offline but when I enable ActiveX on IE it goes wrong again. I think it has something to do with my optimacy on the page CLASS.

Comment: oh ok.. I get it.. I thought it was in the css. :)

Comment: I removed the optimacy in .PAGE and it still wants something to run in IE.

Comment: Could you post the activeX since the issue is probably not in css?

Comment: I don't know what is making the ActiveX, I disabled it in my browser.